# Should we have a Database Server without an External IP?

Tags: database, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I was thinking not to set any External IP Addresses on the cockroach database cluster that I will be launching, as I would be connecting to the cluster using the Internal IP Addresses itself.
I am deploying the cluster on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and would have other application servers that would have External IPs and would interface with the Database Cluster.
I wanted to know, if there are any drawbacks or generally not a good practice to proceed with the above configuration.

Comment: Why did I get a down rating on the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it is a good decision to avoid external IPs as much as possible, especially for databases and backend servers. it is an increase in security on the expense of convince in connecting (e.g. direct SSH).

You'll be able to SSH to such servers as needed by opening SSH tunnels from other VMs in the same VPC or VPN (openvpn, tinc, ..).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is exactly what I was thinking.
I know this will be out there in the internet, but wanted to know, how to I, "SSH to such servers as needed by opening SSH tunnels from other VMs in the same VPC or VPN (openvpn, tinc, ..).".

Comment: gcloud compute ssh server-with-ext-ip -- -L8022:private-ip-of-server-without-ext-ip:22 and then ssh to localhost 8022